# Is there a way to redirect my homepage to a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Is it possible to make it so when a visitor types `example.com` they end up at `example.com/sub/folder/`, i.e. the URL bar will display `example.com/sub/folder/`?

This is my .htaccess file right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteMatch 301 ^/$ /sub/folder
```

or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```